# nodeenv cannot install node.js

Tags: python, node.js

On RedHat Enterprise 7, trying to install node.js inside of a nodeenv (`0.13.6`) in a Python virtual environment (Python 2.7). When I do `nodeenv -p`, I get `OSError: Command make --jobs=2 failed with error code 2`...googling, the only reference to this is [here](http://kartoza.com/nodeenv-how-to-install-nodejs-in-a-python-virtualenv/). Not super useful for me, because I am already trying to install the newest version of node (4.2.1). Full trace of this is below:

```
$ nodeenv -p
 * Install node (4.2.1..Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/bin/nodeenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 891, in main
    create_environment(env_dir, opt)
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 732, in create_environment
    install_node(env_dir, src_dir, opt)
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 608, in install_node
    build_node_from_src(env_dir, src_dir, node_src_dir, opt)
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 577, in build_node_from_src
    callit([make_cmd] + make_opts, opt.verbose, True, node_src_dir, env)
  File "/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nodeenv.py", line 461, in callit
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command make --jobs=2 failed with error code 2
```

I then tried to install from prebuilt, using the instructions in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/issues/133).

`nodeenv -p --prebuilt`

That seemed to work...

```
 * Install node (4.2.1... done.
 * Appending data to /usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/bin/activate
```

Except nothing actually installed -- tab completing shows no `node` or `npm` install (I have deactivated and re-activated the virtual environment):

```
$ no
nodeenv      nohup        nologin      notify-send
$ np
$ nproc
```

My other installs worked with the same instructions, so I'm at a loss for debugging this. Any hints or suggestions? If this is a permissions issue, where do I need to set / change them? The user already owns the virtual environment directory...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I don't have a solution to the root cause (I suspect some sort of issue / conflict with `make` on my server), but I managed to get it installed via `--prebuilt`. I had to manually delete the `node.js` source from `/usr/local/pythonenvs/producer/src/node-v4.2.1/`, because the `--prebuilt` option was trying to copy those as if they were binaries. After deleting the directory, I downloaded / extracted from nodejs.org into the virtual environment's `src` directory. Then, the `nodeenv -p --prebuilt` command works fine.